# C language i dont understand prime number sorting code

Tags: c

I found a code when I type a number using scanf I take the number and see what prime numbers are under the number I typed. THis is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i,j,scan;

    printf("Enter a value:");

    scanf("%d",&scan);

    for(i=2;i<scan;i++){
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++){  
            if(i%j==0){ 
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(i==j){
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When my input is 10 for example i got 2,3,5,7.

I still don't understand for example if i=4 and j=2.

`4%2` doesn't give a remainder of 0, so we then go to `4%3` still no remainder so we then goto 4%4 which 4%4=0, but why is it not getting printed?

Comment: `4 % 2 == 0`, which will `break` out of the inner loop. Then `i = 4` will be compared to `j = 2`. They are not equal, hence the `printf` instruction will not be reached and the outer loop will get to the next iteration (`i = 5`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, have a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Just a hint -- whenever you start to think *"C language i dont understand ..."* -- it's usually not the language that is at fault.

Comment: When there are two `for` and a `break` in the code it is always the fault of the c language even after 30 years ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in understanding the code is here:

> 4%2 doesn't give a remainder of 0, so we then go to 4%3 still no remainder so we then goto 4%4 which 4%4=0, but why is it not getting printed?

You say "`4%2` doesn't give a remainder of 0" but that is wrong.

**`4%2` will give the result 0**, i.e. `4 = 2 * 2 + 0` so the remainder **is** zero.

Therefore you'll not goto `4%3`. Instead it will break the inner-loop and `i` will become 5 and `j` will become 2. In other words - the next remainder test will be `5%2`. The test `4%4` is never performed.